# Updating Fields in Access Query Involving Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I am trying to use a query to grab data from 3 tables.  All share the same primary key (`customer_id`).  The data is obtained easily enough but I am having trouble making the data editable in MS-Access. The issue arises when there is a `customer_id` in `table1` but not yet one in `table2`.  When I try entering in a value for eggs, Access will tell me

> You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in 'table1'

The code I am trying to use is below:

```
select table1.customer_id, table3.eggs     
FROM (table1 Left JOIN table2 ON table1.customer_id=table2.customer_id) 
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.customer_id=table3.customer_id
```

In troubleshooting I took out the second table (`table2`) from the code so there was only one `LEFT JOIN` present to connect `table1` and `table3`.  When I did this, Access would create a new row in `table3` for the `customer_id` listed and input the value to the "egg" field as expected.

I can't figure out how to make edits and updates possible for all 3 tables, any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Queries with outer joins may end up with resulting records which are not updatable. Can you use regular joins instead?  Also, your two selected fields come from two separate tables when it looks like table3 also has the customer ID field.

Here's a paper I wrote: Dealing with Non-Updateable Microsoft Access Queries and the Use of Temporary Tables (http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/non-updateable/index.html)

Part of our Microsoft Access Query Help Center (http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/help-center.html)